# Is there path intellisense for python in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, pycharm

I am wondering if there is a path intellisense for python in VS Code.

In pycharm if you wanted to open a file in your script:

```
with open("file_path") as file:
```

It will promt the file if it is in your current working directory.  Is there a way to do this in VS Code? Should path intellisense do this and I just don't have the settings correct for python? Or might there be another extension or a setting where I can achieve this behavior.

Thanks!

I have installed the extension "path intellisense" but it does not quite work how I was hoping and appears to be more of a JS extension.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else wondering about this it looks like the 'Path Autocomplete' extension by Mihai Vilcu does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support but I would suggest [Path Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete). It's based on [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense).

With <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> you can trigger the intellisense. Characters like `/` also triggers it.